# Is there a simple way to convert a list to a sequence?

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence

I have a list of couples like this for example :

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}
```

In practice my list can be of any size.

I need to put a condition in `ArgMin` such as :

$(m_1,m_2) \notin list $

For example $(1,2)$ would return false here.

One way to do it is to build a sequence from this table:

```
Table[{mj1, mj2} != list[[i]], {i, 1, 2}]
```

So, how can I simply convert this table into a sequence? I have seen way to do it but it seems very complicated (combination of various function).

Isn't there a built-in function that allows this?

Or if there isn't, what is the most lisible way to do it (if you could avoid symbols such as `#`, `?`, etc., it would be nice, I only understand the `@` symbols now).

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `ArgMin` expression you are concerned with. Without it, your question is too opaque.

Comment: What do you mean by "sequence"?  `Sequence @@ Table[...]`?  A `List` is ordered, so it already represents a mathematical sequence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has posted a [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149295/) which is an improved version of this one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, `MemberQ` will do the trick.

```
MemberQ[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {1, 2}]
```

returns `True`

Comment: (+1) Or, possibly, `FreeQ[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {1, 2}]` if the OP requires `false`?.  This one contains a '#', but nothing too difficult?: `FreeQ[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, #] & /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}}` => {False, False, True}