# What is wrong with my ArgMin expression?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need to find the minimum of a function $mj_1^2+mj_2^2$ where my $mj$ are constrained.

I wrote this expression:

```
ArgMin[
  {mj1^2 + mj2^2, mj1 == (M1 + 1)*p1, p1 ∈ Integers, 
   mj2 == (M2 + 1)*p2, p2 ∈ Integers, 
   MemberQ[{mj1, mj2} , couplesm]}, {mj1, mj2}]
```

Indeed, my `mj`'s must be multiples of `Mj + 1`, and they musn't be part of a list given by `couplesm`.

When I evaluate it, I get the following message;

> ArgMin::infeas: There are no values of {mj1, mj2} for which the constraints False are satisfied and the objective function mj1^2 + mj2^2 is real valued.

I even added `p1` and `p2` to the variables of minimization, but it still didn't work.

How can I find the minimum of: $mj_1^2+mj_2^2$, where $mj_i$ is a multiple of $M_i+1$ and where the pairs $(mj_1,mj_2)$ can't be inside of the list `couplesm`?

#### Edit

I wrote the following and the code still doesn't work.

```
couplesm = {{0, 0}}
```

> `{{0, 0}}`

```
ArgMin[
  {mj1^2 + mj2^2, 
   IntegerQ[mj1/(M1 + 1)], IntegerQ[mj2/(M1 + 1)], 
   mj1 ∈ Integers, mj2 ∈ Integers, 
   Sequence @@ Table[{mj1, mj2} != couplesm[[i]], {i, 1, Length[couplesm]}]}, 
  {mj1, mj2}]
```

> ArgMin::infeas: There are no values of {mj1,mj2} for which the constraints False are satisfied and the objective function mj1^2+mj2^2 is real valued.
>
> `{Indeterminate, Indeterminate}`

Comment: What are the definitions of `p1`, `p2` and `couples`?

Comment: $p_1$ and $p_2$ are just positive integers. They are here to symbolise the fact that I want $mji$ to be a multiple of $Mi+1$. couplesm is a list of couples like this : {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}. I don't want (mj1,mj2) to be an element of this list. To take an example you can take couplesm={{0,0}} to start with

Comment: The arguments of `ArgMin` are evaluated first.  Evaluate `MemberQ[{mj1, mj2} , couplesm]` to see where the `False` in the error message comes from.

Comment: I don't understand. I can't evaluate it first as mj1 and mj2 are changed by Argmin. They don't have a value outside of this function ?

Comment: I want you to tell us the actual values you used for `p1`, `p2` and `couplesm` when you evaluated your expression.

Comment: I didn't chose any value for p1 and p2. Maybe the problem is here, but I  don't know how to tell him that mji has to be multiple of Mi+1 else. couplesm={{0,0}}

Comment: maybe `IntegerQ[mj1/(M1 + 1)]`

Comment: It still does'nt work :(

Comment: You need to @user, where "user" is the user name, to notify someone of your reply.

Comment: "I can't evaluate it first as mj1 and mj2 are changed by Argmin." -- Actually, *Mathematica* evaluates it first, before passing the result `False` to `ArgMin[]`.  Therefore `ArgMin[]` never has a chance to change `mj1` or `mj2` or see whether the pair of values are a member of `couplesm`. You need a function like `memQ[x1_Integer, x2_Integer] := MemberQ[{x1, x2}, couplesm]`., and then replace `MemberQ[{mj1, mj2} , couplesm]` with `memQ[{mj1, mj2}]`.

Comment: I think it is time for you to conclude you aren't going to solve your problem with `ArgMin`. I recommend you reconsider the problem at the mathematics level and formulate a different solution strategy.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this?

```
couplesm = {{0, 0}, {3, 0}};

Block[{M1 = 2, mj1 = (M1 + 1) m1, mj2 = (M1 + 1) m2},
 ArgMin[
  {mj1^2 + mj2^2,
   AllTrue[couplesm, {mj1, mj2} != # &]},
  {m1, m2},
  Integers]
 ]
(*  {-1, 0}  *)
```

In general, avoid functions that end in `Q`, such as `IntegerQ` and `MemberQ`, in constructing equations and constraints for solvers.  Almost all of them evaluate to `True` or `False` immediately, that is, before values are substituted for the variables.  If, for some reason, you need to use one, you need to construct a wrapper function that will evaluate the `Q` function only after the variables have been given numeric values (using [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)).

Comment: Are the `m1 ∈ Integers` and `m2 ∈ Integers` necessary when you're setting the domain to be Integers?

Comment: @aardvark2012 No, I meant to get rid of them. Thanks for pointing it out.